# position a child window

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I need help with positioning a child window created using

```
var win:myWindow = new myWindow();
```

where `myWindow.mxml` contains `<s:Window.......`

The child window does open as desired. However I would like to place it at a specific (x,y) position with reference to the `WindowsApplication`.

I have tried

```
var parentWindowHandle:* = nativeApllcaition.nativeApplication.openedWindows[0];

win.x = parentWindowHandle.x + 200;
```

However, this does not work. The content of the myWindow gets shifted by 200. (myWindow.mxml contains only a label. This label shifts by 200 to the right. Not exactly what I wanted).

The `parentWindowHandle` is correct. I have checked it using `Alert.show(parentWindowHandle.title)` which is displayed correctly.

I am pretty new to Adobe AIR.

EDIT:
I tried to do win.x=200 as suggested. However the content seems to be moving not the window.

Comment: i suggest to use <mx:Window> instead of <s:Window> , i use <s:WindowesApplication> with <mx:Window> and every thing good , there is no sheft .

Comment: @sameer H Ibra, didnot work. My label in myWin gets shifted. I cant get the window to open where i want.

Answer (score 0):

for moving the window :

```
win.nativeWindow.x = 200;
```

Comment: H Ibra, nativewindow is returning null. hence getting error "cannot accessmethod or property of null object reference

Comment: i make project <s:WindowesApplication> then i add <s:Window> , in creation complete function for main class in <s:WindowesApplication> i define these lines and work good with x and y position : `     var win:myWindow = new myWindow();
    win.open();
    win.nativeWindow.x = 200;
    win.nativeWindow.y = 200;`

Comment: @SameerH.Ibra: You may add the information in your comment to the answer as well.